# Best way to determine direction of induced voltage

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I'm trying to get a handle on how to determine the polarity of induced voltage (and by extension the direction of current) in a conductor that interacts with a magnetic field.

I've followed various threads and online  resources but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. The main obstacle is that the way a conductor could interact with a magnetic field is very varied:

- open wire vs closed-circuit current -carrying conductor
- single wire vs coil
- wire is moved relative to the field vs field is moved relative to the wire
- wire is moved up/down vs left,
  /Right vs sideways while running the length of the field vs perpendicularly along the field and running the length of the wire

Every law/rule/aid seems to have caveats: either it requires coils or current to flow or it applies to generators specifically and so on.

How do you determine the above in a reliable way? Any good resources that cover the subject in some depth would also be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Read about Lenz's law on the web.  It is good intuitive approach.

Comment: Agreed. It covers every case. But you do need to know a couple of other rules as well: the right hand grip (or screw) rule relating direction of magnetic field around a current-carrying conductor to the current direction, and the Lorentz force law or a rough equivalent such as Fleming's left hand motor rule.

Answer (score 0):

Take a long wire, and make several loops in the ground, attaching each end to a DC voltmeter.

Take a magnet where the north and south pole was checked using a compass. The north pole is repelled by the side of the needle that points north.

Put the magnet inside the loop with the North facing up, while looking at the display of the voltmeter. Change sides quickly. That means: the B field that was pointing downward is now pointing upwards, it increased upwards.

Check the sign of the display readings while changing sides of the magnet and verify the rule of the left hand.